# Change Eclipse "Build Automatically" time interval?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to change the default time interval for an automatic build in Eclipse?

Comment: What do you mean?  The automatic build is triggered by a resource change, like saving a source file or refreshing the project after external changes.  I don't think it builds at set intervals unless something changed, and it won't *wait* for a certain period if something *has* changed.

Comment: I guess he is asking is there a way to throttle that automatic build. I doubt it.

Comment: @Mark: What @RedBlue said. ;) Would be nice to sync (or a-sync) with other scripts being run that render/affect project files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off build automatically (in the project menu, uncheck build automatically) and then get into the habit of build each time you decide to start your app/application (ctrl + b).

Why do you want this though?  As @Nirmal pointed out, there isn't a way to do exactly what you're asking for.  Usually though - from my experience - building is pretty fast and when you do build automatically it doesn't have to run a full build.  Is it taking forever to validate your javascript?  I've had this problem with more recent versions of eclipse, but not the most recent.  If this is the case, just search stackoverflow/google for turning off javascript validation in Eclipse.

Comment: Funny you should mention the JS validation. I was just thinking the same.

Answer (score 1):

it will automatically build content that is changed , no need explicit interval to define